# c# Connection WPF with an online database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I am working on a new system and I want to connect my system with an online database although I tried somethings which I found online, mostly they were with mysql and not micrsoft sql and I tried to install the mysql libraries from visual studio although I couldn't find them so I stayed with the option of using microsoft sql.

So far I worked with my pc server to do a simple connection to work with but know I am trying to connect it with xampp.

```
static string server = "localhost";

static string database = "tss";

static string username = "root";

static string password = "";

static string connection = "server=" + server + ";" + "database=" + database + ";"+"UID=" + username + ";" + "password=" + password + ";";

protected static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
```

Since I need a connection with the database so that my application could work, I keep getting this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)".

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and connect to database.  The Server and Instance of Server on the login page should be the same as the connection string in c#.

Comment: Why are you using all these variables to build a connection string? You should put your connection string in the config file and be done with it. You do NOT want to build up a connection string like this in code. If you ever change anything you will have to come back and update your code everywhere.

Comment: Already did that. I want to use an online database so the system can be used anywhere without the need of installing a server on the pc

Comment: Sean Lange- It's in a class so I am calling it once.

Comment: This could be a number of things. Is the sql server configured to listen to TCP/IP and Named Pipes ? Are both firewalls configered ? Is the server up and running ? etc...

Comment: Even so...why use variables like this? As for the error at hand it could be a whole list of stuff.

Comment: GuidoG- The server is fine.  I need to check the configuration of the sql server and the firewall as well.

Comment: If your code with variables is in a class and is only called once makes no difference. When the server changes (moved to another machine for example) you will have to open your class and alter the variables. Why not just store the connectionstring in the config file ?

Comment: Sean Lange - It's just for testing to see if it works I would do the connection as one once it works. It's not a big deal and totally irreverent with my problem.

Comment: GuidoG -  configuration are both ok..